# Multiple League of Legends Icons on Dock

Tags: macos, mojave, dock, icon

I have kept the application League of Legends in my dock since I use it very often, however, whenever I launch the application, it creates another icon in the dock.

One icon has a "running" dot and the other doesn't.

Is there a way to fix this issue or remove the second icon?

[image: Here is a photo to help you see:]

Comment: Hold and drag it on out of the dock..?

Comment: Can you right-click and reveal in Finder for both? Are they the same application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOS Mojave has a configuration to show recently used application icon in the Dock. In order to disable it, uncheck **Show recent applications** in Dock under ***System Preferences → Dock.***

Application with support for opening documents minimize into Dock in their own separate icon. To disable that behavior, check to **Minimise windows into application** icon under **System Preferences** → **Dock**.

[image]